# Dar value de variable a un INPUT

Tags: javascript, html

Hola tengo un codigo que esta conectado a un API y estoy recibiendo los datos que necesito,  pero quiero hacer que el valor que esta capturando mi variable lo tenga el input de más abajo. como puedo hacer esta declaracion?

```
<html>
  <body>
   
  <link href='https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/autocomplete-lhc-versions/17.0.2/autocomplete-lhc.min.css' rel="stylesheet">
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/autocomplete-lhc-versions/17.0.2/autocomplete-lhc.min.js'></script>
<form><input type="text" id="npi_org" placeholder="Provider name or NPI" autocomplete="on" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" class="search_field">
<button type="button" onclick="info()">Apply</button></form>
<script>
  new Def.Autocompleter.Search(
  'npi_org',
  'https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/api/npi_org/v3/search',
  {tableFormat: true, valueCols: [0, 1, 3],
    colHeaders: ['Name', 'NPI', 'Type', 'Practice Address']
  
  });
  function info(){
    var pcpinfo=document.getElementById("npi_org").value;
    var pcp = pcpinfo.split('-');
    console.log(pcp[0]);
    console.log(pcp[1]);
    console.log(pcp[2]);
 }
</script>
<input type="text" id="field120594500" name="field120594500" size="50" required="" value="" class="fsField fsFormatText fsRequired   " aria-required="true">
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola colega debes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Captura el elemento con querySelector y accede al valor con .value

```js
let $input = document.querySelector('#field120594500').value;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field120594500" name="field120594500" size="50" required="" value="" class="fsField fsFormatText fsRequired   " aria-required="true">
```

2. Simplemente llamas a tu variable y le pasas el valor de esta al input:

```js
let miVariable = //aqui va el valor de este variable;
let $input = document.querySelector('#field120594500').value;
//El valor del input es igual al valor de miVariable
$input = mivariable
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field120594500" name="field120594500" size="50" required="" value="" class="fsField fsFormatText fsRequired   " aria-required="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Este fue el codigo con el cual solucione mi inquietud

```
  function info(){
var pcpinfo=document.getElementById("npi_org").value;
var vecpcp = pcpinfo.split('-');
document.getElementById("field120594517").value=vecpcp[0];
document.getElementById("field120594518").value=vecpcp[2];
document.getElementById("field120594519").value=vecpcp[1];
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).